# eclipse changing text on button click

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick

I'm experiencing some probles with my andorid app I'm currently developing in eclipse bundle. 
I want to make a simple text change on a button click but unfortunately, when I run the app on my device it stops working. The app crashes on my device, but has no errors in eclipse.

This is my code:

```
final TextView chores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chores);
Button choreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choreButton);

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String next = "Go make some Coffee.";
        chores.setText(next);
    }
};
choreButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Thanks for your help! :)

so this is the XML file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.zargi.choreme.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:background="#6EFF70" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choremehead"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Are you bored? Then go and..."
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/choremehead"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/chore"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/choreButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/chores"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:text="Enlighten me!" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is what I wrote in java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView chores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chores);
        Button choreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choreButton);

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String next = "Go make some Coffee.";
                chores.setText(next);
            }
        };
        choreButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

and here's the logcat, now there are some errors that weren't there before..

```
09-02 04:48:06.650: D/AndroidRuntime(972): Shutting down VM
09-02 04:48:06.650: W/dalvikvm(972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a9dba8)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Process: com.zargi.choreme, PID: 972
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zargi.choreme/com.zargi.choreme.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.zargi.choreme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-02 04:48:06.670: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  ... 11 more
09-02 04:48:48.726: I/Process(972): Sending signal. PID: 972 SIG: 9
```

androidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zargi.choreme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zargi.choreme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As is said I don't see any errors in logcat but my app crashes on a mobile phone as on a AVD. I'm also new to java programming so sorry if I make any stupid mistakes :D

Comment: Post tha logcat trace.

Comment: you will get some errors in logcat, go to DDMS select your emulator and then check logcat

Comment: [2014-09-02 10:40:10 - ChoreME] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

That is the only error I get

Comment: That's the eclipse output window, not the LogCat

Comment: Your app may be running in emulator, go to emulator and come out from app then run it again

Comment: yes I know, I dont get any errors in the logcat

Comment: can you please post xml as well as activity code ?

Comment: What's line MainActivity.java:38?

Comment: here is all i got :) 
I receive an error for this line in the log cat:    choreButton.setOnClickListener(listener);

Comment: choreButton.setOnClickListener(listener); is on line 38

Comment: What is your layout name???

Comment: This `should` work. What is null. choreButton or listener? Please debug.

Comment: There is no issue. Clean your project and rebuild it

Comment: when I debug I get nothing, debugger's output = "source not found"

Comment: I already did it, for the 3rd time, started new projects and started from the begining, always the same, it works if I take out the onClick method, else not

Comment: Ok then check your `Button` and `TextView` are in `activity_main.xml` file.

Comment: no they weren't, it works now! thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

A few options here

1. `chores` is `null`
2. `choreButton` is `null`

Insert Log statements, in Android preferably via a framework or `Log.d(String, String)` (and even the good old `System.out.println(String)` works).

Like

```
Log.d("nullcheck", "chores?" + (chores == null) + " chorebutton?" + (choreButton == null));
```

However, presumably, you try to initialize the views **before(!)** `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. Do it like below, and you're fine (if, and only if your xml is inflated properly, and the id's exist on the xml)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView chores;
    Button choreButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chores = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chores);
        choreButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choreButton);

        //Here a log statement. Insert it in your code, run the app, and examine the output
        Log.d("nullcheck", "chores?" + (chores == null) + " chorebutton?" + (choreButton == null));

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String next = "Go make some Coffee.";
                chores.setText(next);
            }
        };
        choreButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

That being said, it is a **MUST** that both `R.id.chores` and `R.id.choreButton` are declared in your xml (in my example `activity_main.xml`)

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chores"
        ... />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choreButton"
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So must check your `Button` and `TextView` are in `activity_main.xml` file.